# Compare only time in Date - javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I compare just time in js?
Let's say I have 2 dates :

```
date1 = Tue Apr 11 2017 12:30:00
date2 = Tue Apr 7 2017 02:30:00
```

and now I want to make if statement

```
if(time of the day in date1 is after time of the day in date2) {
    // do something
}
```

How can I achieve this in clean and nice way?

Comment: substring out those positions from the end

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**.If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: fetch time from your date string by either break it or by javascript functions like gethours(), getminutes()

Comment: How is it possible `Tue Apr 11 2017` and `Tue Apr 7 2017` represent same day?

Comment: @ozil ach my bad

Comment: @ozil Forget about that Friday feeling as it's now Tuesday today :c

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I know I can do "parser" but I was looking for simpler way, unfortunately there isn't any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use 3rd party libraries, have a look at the [moment library](https://momentjs.com). It has an [isBefore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before) and [isAfter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after) methods that should do what you want.

If you can't use 3rd party libraries, then you can use the `getHours()`, `getMinutes()`, and `getSeconds()` properties on the Date object.